# Is Material TextAppearance usefull for handle different textSize

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I just discover the textAppearence keyword and the `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents`

Exemple of use :

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_soft_bold"
     android:text="@string/ads_header_last"
     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
     android:textColor="@color/charcoal_grey" />
```

If we look like the `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5` we found this

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline">
<item name="fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
<item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
```

The `textSize` inside is 24sp I'm confused because I thought the textAppearence keyword can manage the textSize for all screen device

If we use

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline"
```

The `TextAppearance.Material.Headline` style is

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Material.Headline">
    <item name="textSize">@dimen/text_size_headline_material</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/font_family_headline_material</item>
    <item name="textColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and the `@dimen/text_size_headline_material` is correctly using different dimens for different screen size

```
<dimen name="text_size_headline_material">24sp</dimen>
<dimen name="text_size_headline_material">18sp</dimen>
etc...
```

Why the TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5 have not the same configuration ?
And I cannot use `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline"` because it's require API 21

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5` is `<h5>` tag so it has fix text size in style, that's why if you are going to use this style you can not change text size, this is header tag

this will be same for all type of devices

[image]

**To make changes in style**

make your own `style` with header `parent` and use it in your `TextView`

```
<style name="TvStyle" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5">
     <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I didn't know that, if it has fix text size it's not really usefull do you know if Android have another style who can be use with textApparence ?

Comment: you can make your own style

Comment: Yes I know but if android have already done it I prefer to use it